# Issue while copying a Configuration File from a TFTP Server to Cisco IOS Router

Tags: tftp, cisco-ios

I have a Ubuntu machine which acts as a TFTP Server. I want to configure my cisco ios routers to take configuration from this TFTP server at boot time.

I have a few doubts-
Where do I store the configuration file for my cisco router in the TFTP Server?
Currently, I have created two temp folders in /var/lib/tftpboot-

```
automation@automation:/var/lib/tftpboot$ ls -l
total 8
drwx------ 2 tftp tftp 4096 Mar 31 15:37 ExrZHRa-incoming
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 31 15:52 TXJla-outgoing

automation@automation:/var/lib/tftpboot$ tree
.
├── ExrZHRa-incoming [error opening dir]
└── TXJla-outgoing
    └── R1.txt

2 directories, 1 file
```

As per Cisco's documentation, this is the syntax to get a file from TFTP server-

```
copy tftp: [[[//location ]/directory ]/filename ] nvram:startup-config 

Example:
Device# copy tftp://server1/dir10/datasource nvram:startup-config
```

As per my understanding, the `location` will be IP of my TFTP Server and `filename` will be the actual config file I want to load. But what should be configured in the `directory`? I tried with `/var/lib/tftpboot/TXJla-outgoing` but it didn't work. Error-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A8DT.png)

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be just

```
copy tftp://192.168.1.1/R1.txt running-config
```

It looks like you are using tftp-hda.  Did you follow this guide ?
https://medium.com/@Sciri/configuring-a-tftp-server-on-ubuntu-for-switch-upgrades-and-maintenance-caf5b6833148

Comment: No, because `R1.txt` resides inside of the `TXJla-outgoing` folder within `tftproot.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
copy tftp://192.168.1.1/TXJla-outgoing/R1.txt nvram:startup-config
```

The URL of anything you download via TFTP starts from the root of your TFTP server which is `/var/lib/tftpboot`